# YouTube Embed Dissapears on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I have a WYSIWIG editor located at [0TM.CO](http://0tm.co/), and I am currently implementing a YouTube Videos Feature.

The issue is that as soon as the user pushes the "publish" button, the YouTube embed disappears and the engine processes the page as if the embed was never there.

JS code that processes publishing:

```
$("#publish").click(function () {
    saveAll();
    var e = $("display").html();
    var t = '<form id="parse" action="engine.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="html" value="' + encodeURIComponent(e) + '"><input type="hidden" name="buttons" value="' + buttons + '"><input type="hidden" name="contents" value="' + contents + '"></form>';
    $("display").html($("display").html() + t);
    $("#parse").submit()
});
```

Function saveAll:

```
function saveAll() {
    $("#title-holder").attr("id", "title");
    $("#subtitle-holder").attr("id", "subtitle");
    $("#title").text($("#set-title").val());
    $("#subtitle").text($("#set-subtitle").val());
    for (var e = 0; e < buttons; e++) {
        $("#btn-" + e + "-holder").attr("id", "btn-" + e);
        $("#btn-" + e).attr("val", $("#set-btn-" + e).val());
        if (validateURL($("#set-btn-" + e).val())) {
            $("#btn-" + e).attr("fhref", $("#set-btn-" + e).val());
            $("#btn-" + e).attr("ftarget", "_blank");
            $("#btn-" + e).attr("class", "btn btn-primary");
            $("#btn-" + e).text($("#set-btn-" + e).val().replace(/.*?:\/\//g, ""))
        } else {
            $("#btn-" + e).text($("#set-btn-" + e).val())
        }
    }
    for (var e = 0; e < contents; e++) {
        if ($("#content-edit-" + e).length) {
            $("#content-" + e).attr("onclick", "contentEdit(" + e + ")");
            $("#content-" + e).attr("content", $("#content-edit-" + e).val());
            $("#content-" + e).html($("#content-edit-" + e).val().replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<iframe class="complimentary" width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'))
        }
    }
}
```

[Click Here for Full JS Code](http://0tm.co/main.js)

I am relatively new to StackOverflow, sorry if I did something wrong here.